# Style hosted form for addPayment method Authorize.net

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

I'm wondering if anyone of you knows how to style the appearance of the hosted form for the `addPayment` API method of [Authorize.net](http://www.authorize.net/)

I'm having a hard time with their documentation and I try to add a logo or change the font colors.
Their docs tell to send a hidden input on the request with certain name and values. One I've tried for the font color is:

`%input{type: 'hidden', name: 'x_color_text', value: "ffcc00"}`
but nothing changes. Anyone out there?